# Ruby: Implementing class with Hash-like syntactic sugar

Tags: ruby

I I want to create a `class MyList`, that I can have the syntactic of an `Array` for initialization, like:

```
ml = MyList.new [1, 2, 3]
```

I can implement it by implementing the function `self.[]`, like in the excerpt below:

```
class MyList
  def self.[] *array
   self.new array
  end

  def initialize enum = nil, &block
   # ....
  end
end
```

And how can I implement a `class MyHash`, to be initialized as

```
mh = MyHash.new { 1 => 1, 2 => 2}
# mh =  { 1 => 1, 2 => 2} # post edit: old version, that caused confusion on this question.
```

is there a method that I implement in my class, and how? If not, what's so special about the `{ a =>b }` notation?

**Post-Duplicate mark explanation** -- The question was not well stated, but my intent  was not duplicated. In fact, just like I have

```
ml = MyList.new [1, 2, 3]
```

I meant to have:

```
mh = MyHash.new { 1 => 1, 2 => 2}
```

Already answering to myself, that is probably not possible, because Ruby will confuse with a block being passed by parameter, but I can have

```
mh = MyHash.new ({ 1 => 1, 2 => 2})
```

by defining:

```
class MyHash

  def initialize hash
   # ....
  end
end
```

Comment: If there were such feature, how could Ruby interpreter know that `{1 => 1, 2 => 2}` is a `MyHash` not a `Hash`?

Comment: @Aetherus: When you redefine `class Hash ; def size ; 0; end ; end; `, how does Ruby know which Hash.size is to be used? But nevermind, the question wasn't well explained....